# Reference smarty array element by value?

Tags: arrays, smarty

Total newbie with smarty; I did try to research before asking but couldn't figure this out.  My application provides me with a nested array structure like this:

```
custom_fields => Array (2)
  0 => Array (6)
    name => "key-specs"
    type => "textarea"
    code => "key-specs"
    value => "here are some product specifications"
    sd => "05/01/2013 - 09:25:44 PM"
    titled => ""
  1 => Array (6)
    name => "key-specs-li-class"
    type => "dropdownlist"
    code => "key-specs-li-class"
    value => "flg4_icon"
    sd => "05/01/2013 - 09:25:44 PM"
    titled => ""
```

Instead of looping through the array, I'd really like to simply reference the outer array by the "name" dimension within the inner array.  For example, I know that the name "key-specs" exists somewhere in the array, and all I want to do is quickly retrieve the "value" string that resides at the same index.

Any way to do this type of direct referencing, or am I going to have to loop?

Comment: In order to get the value "key-specs" you need to reference the `key`, in this case `name`. If you know for sure it is going to be in a specific location using smarty you could do `custom_fields.0.name' and then check if is "key-specs". If you know "key-specs" is always in the array and you need it, why are you looking for it. Have a string $key_specs = "key_specs".

Comment: thanks...I didn't design the app that is providing this structure, but I am using it in my HTML.  It will always be at the same index so hardcoding the index value shouldn't be a problem - thanks.